# Is there a list of all cryptocoin currencies?

Tags: currencies, decentralization

Apart from bitcoin, I know few other crypto currencies (by this I mean currency which works in a similar way to bitcon). They are:

- namecoin
- lightcoin
- ripple

I also heard about SolidCoin, but as far as I understood it is already dead.

Is this everything or am I missing something

Comment: Not that I can think of. There are a lot of websites that claim to be about an alternative cryptocurrency, but are actually spam or one-man-projects that never took off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitcoin wiki has a list:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_alternative_cryptocurrencies

There is a forum dedicated to alternative coins at bitcointalk:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=67.0